# Integer zeros of $S(x) = \sum_{K=0}^{(N-1)/2} \binom{N+2}{2K+1} (-1)^{K} x^{N-(2K+1)}$ for $N \equiv 3$ (mod $4$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

For concreteness, when expanded, $S$ looks like this:

$$S(x) = \binom{N+2}{1} x^{N-1} - \binom{N+2}{3} x^{N-3} + \binom{N+2}{5} x^{N-5} - \cdots - \binom{N+2}{N}$$

(The last term is necessarily negative since $N \equiv 3$ mod $4$ implies $(N-1)/2 \equiv 1$ mod $4$.) According to the CAS SymPy, it also has the closed form

$$S(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{2 x \left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{\frac{N+1}{2}} \cos{\left(\left(N + 1\right) \operatorname{atan}{\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)} \right)} + x^{N + 1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{x^{2} + 1}}{\left|{x}\right|}\right)^{N} \left(x^{2} + 1\right) \sin{\left(N \operatorname{atan}{\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)} \right)}}{x^{3}} & \text{for}\: \frac{1}{x^{2}} \leq 1 \\\frac{x^{N} \sum_{K=0}^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \left(-1\right)^{K} x^{- 2 K} {\binom{N + 2}{2 K + 1}}}{x} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I am interested in this summation as it is involved in finding the integer solutions to $u^n = v^2 + 1$, where $n \equiv 1$ mod $4$. If $x$ is an integer zero of $S$, then it satisfies the equation $(x+i)^n = v+i$ for $v \neq 0$.

After examining $S$ for several small $N$, it seems plausible that $S$ has no integer zeros. How could I proceed to check if this claim holds or not?